# Ignore capital letter rule when word is preceded by a shortcut

Tags: spell-checking

I want to use the spelling rule: `begin first word in a sentence with capital letter`, but Vim faultily recognises the end of a sentence when I use shortcuts that end with a dot.

The problem exists only with my native language. When using `en_gb` this sentence is correct:

```
He likes many pets, e.g. cats.
```

But the Polish version is not correct (when using `pl` as the spelling language):

```
On lubi różne zwierzęta, np. koty.
```

The word `koty` is marked with the capital letter error. Vim thinks that the dot that belongs to the shortcut `np.` marks the end of sentence.

I tried to modify the `spellcapcheck` setting by adding the `negative look behind` to the regex:

```
:set spellcapcheck=(?<!np)[.?!]\_[\])'" \t]\+
```

This modification broke the rule entirely (Vim stopped showing capital letter error everywhere). Maybe my regex is not correct. But I also think I look at the wrong place to configure it, as the `spellcapcheck` setting is not modified when the I set `en_gb` on:

```
:set spellcapcheck?
spellcapcheck=[.?!]\_[\])'"^I ]\+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to add the shortcut to the dictionary, including the dot. So I expect that in case of `en_gb` the word `e.g.` is included in the default dictionary.

The problem is, you cannot use `zg` to add the shortcut to the dictionary, because in this case only `np` will be added, not `np.`. You need to add the line:

```
np.
```

in the `$HOME/.vim/spell/pl.utf-8.add` file manually.

Please mind that the change will not take affect until the binary file `$HOME/.vim/spell/pl.utf-8.add.spl` is recompiled. You can trigger its recompilation by adding another word to the dictionary, this time from Vim, using `zg` (I don't know another way to do this). It does not have to be a word unknown to the default dictionary.

Comment: Even better. Just visually select the word including the point and add it via `zg`.