# Deactivate SpellCap-Check after Abbreviation

Tags: spell-checking

Vim highlight SpellCap errors after every fullstop. Also after abbreviations:

```
i.e. without
```

Here `without` gets the SpellCap highlight. This is obious no error, and renders the SpellCap function rather useless for me.
Is there a way to define abbreviations in vim, so that there is no SpellCap placed afterwards?

Comment: Duplicate question that has a working answer: [Ignore capital letter rule when word is preceded by a shortcut](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/ignore-capital-letter-rule-when-word-is-preceded-by-a-shortcut)

Answer (score 4):

`SpellCap` does not identify misspelled words. It tries to point out places where the first word of a sentence is not correctly capitalized. Thus, adding words to your dictionary probably won't help.

Look at `:help 'spellcapcheck'` and you'll see that the setting contains punctuation that should mark the end of a sentence.

I tend to ignore this highlighting. If you can't ignore it *and* you don't need Vim to identify capitalization issues then you could just do `:set spellcapcheck=`.

Otherwise, maybe this information will help root out a more acceptable solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Unfortunaly it is nothing new (it would have been a few days earlier). Looks like it is going to be a plugin project. The Problem ist not, that i can't ignore these errors, the problem is I shouldn't. It should be customer grade in the end. But thank you very much for your answer anyway!

Comment: No problem. I suggest you update your question to reflect your current understanding (e.g. remove reference to adding words to your spellfile) so as to keep future readers on the right track. Also, I'm not convinced yet that this can't be solved through configuration though I haven't yet had time to dig down to the next layer.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the environment that you are in there might be possibilites.

When I write markdown with pandoc or pure LaTex then I put a backslash before the succeeding space of an abbreviation:

```
i.e.\ without
```

Vim will not mark `without` as missspelled and `pandoc` or `latex` will produce a correct space between `i.e.` and `without`.